# Django Auth User Model Set different field name for password

Tags: django, python-3.x

I recently look into Django framework and plan to migrate my old system into it. Therefore, there is legacy mysql database that I need to follow. Is there anyway to change the field name of password of Django User Model? such as "pwd" or "password2".

I got research the Django document, only able to find out changing the username field
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a new class that inherits from user model and set the password field to be whatever you like.

Something like:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='custom_name')
    ...
```

Comment: In particular, derive from AbstractUser, redeclare the `password` field with a `db_field=` kwarg.